# Calculating number of times exactly 2 pairs of consecutive identical letters.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, inclusion-exclusion

I am troubled by this problem, my intuition fails literally and I can't seem to understand why.

> In how many ways can the letters in ARRANGEMENT be arranged so that
> there are exactly two pairs of consecutive identical letters?

My approach:

Number of ways at least two such pairs can occur is $4\choose2$*$\frac {9!}{2!*2!}$

Number of ways at least three such pairs can occur is $4\choose3$*$\frac {8!}{2!}$

Number of ways at least four such pairs can occur is $4\choose4$*$7!$

So total number of ways in which exactly 2 pairs occurs should be $4\choose2$*$\frac{9!}{2!*2!}$ - $4\choose3$*$\frac{8!}{2!}$ + $4\choose4$*$7!$

Answer (score 3):

Your count of the number of ways you can have at least two pairs seems wrong. Perhaps if you explain your calculation, I can help you pinpoint what's wrong.

Let's count, for instance, the number $K$ of permutations in which $AA$ and $RR$ appear, but not $NN$ and not $EE$. (As there are six pairs among A, R, N, E, your final answer will be $6K$.) We have

$$K = (\text{number of perms with AA, RR}) - (\text{number of perms with AA, RR, NN}) - (\text{number of perms with AA, RR, EE}) + (\text{number of perms with AA, RR, NN, EE}).$$

So $K = 9!/(2!)^2 - 2 \cdot 8!/2! + 7! = 11 \cdot 7!.$

Therefore the answer is $6K = 66 \cdot 7! = 332640.$

Comment: Calculation of atleast two pairs is as follows: there are 4 pairs so we choose 2 from them in 4C2 ways. Then we consider the two pairs as two individual letters. So now there are 9 letters out of which 2+2 will be identical so there will be 9!/(2!*2!). So in total 4C2*9!/(2!*2!) Ways.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, say AA and RR are the pairs. You are considering them as a single block each, so you have, in essence, 9 letters, namely, AA, RR, N, N, E, E, G, M, T.  Then you divide by $2! 2!$ because the two Es or the two Ns could trade places. The problem with this approach is that if you have three or four consecutive identical pairs, the permutation will be counted more than once. For example, if AA, RR and NN appear, then you are counting the permutation once for AA, RR, once for AA, NN, and once more for RR, NN.

Comment: Nice exposition without the *formula* (+1) !

Answer (score 3):

> According to the hypothesis for each $1 \leq m \leq t$ ,the number of elements in $S$ that satisfy exactly $m$ of the conditions $c_1 , c_2 , .., c_t $ given by $$E_m= S_m - C(m+1,1)S_{m+1} + C(m+2,2)S_{m+2} - ... + (-1)^{t-m}C(t , t-m) S_{t} $$

So , by using the hypothesis $$E_2= S_2 - C(3,1)S_{3} + C(4,2)S_{4}  $$ where $  S_2= C(4,2) \times 90720 $ , $ S_3= C(4,3) \times 20160 $ , $ S_4= C(4,4) \times 5040$

$S_2$ means the number of all arrangements where $2$ pairs are adjacent among $AA,EE,NN,RR$.

$S_3$ means the number of all arrangements where $3$ pairs are adjacent among $AA,EE,NN,RR$.

$S_4$ means the number of all arrangements where $4$ pairs are adjacent among $AA,EE,NN,RR$.

By calculation answer is $544320 - (3 \times 80640) + (6 \times 5040 ) = 332640$

BE CAREFUL !! This question is different from ordinary  principle of inclusion -exclusion , because it is asked for $\color{red}{exactly}$ $2$ pairs . Hence , I used the generalized version of principle of inclusion -exclusion . When you use principle of inclusion -exclusion directly , you make overcounting . To prevent overcounting , we used the given formula. You can  draw a venn diagram to see how the formula works.

Comment: Your calculations are correct. But why does my intuition fails.

Comment: @rsonx ı have added new  something in the last part

Comment: @rsonx imagine the question like venn diagram , it is the key point

Comment: @rsonx you are making overcounting , to prevent overcounting , we put $3$ in the head of at least three such pairs and put $6$ in the head of $7!$

Comment: @rsonx the formula i gave you is to prevent overcounting when it stated exactly $n$ pairs

Comment: nice, I think I am getting it now. Earlier I was thinking this way, if we eliminate number of ways in which at least 3 pairs can occurs from the number of ways in which at least 2 pairs can occur then we would have the number of ways in which exactly 2 pairs occurs.

Comment: Nice formula, (+1), though I get confused sometimes !

Answer (score 2):

We shall compute  by breaking it into two parts

Glue the two $A's$ and two $E's$ together as $\Bbb A, \Bbb E$ respectively, so we have

$\Bbb A \Bbb E GMTRRNN$ with $\frac{9!}{2!2!} = 90720$ permutations

In part $2$, subtract permutations where neither $R's\; nor\; N's$ are together

Arrangements with $N's$ together = $\frac{8!}{2!}=20160$

Ditto for $R's$ together $= 20160$

Both $N's\;and\; R's$ together $= 7!=5040$

By inclusion- exclusion, neither $R's\;nor N's$ together = $90720- 2*20160+5040=55440$

Thus exactly $A's\; and\; E's$ together $= 55440 $

Finally, there can be $\binom42$ double pairs, giving the answer as $6*55440= \boxed{332640}$